# How is variant_row implemented in database template library(C++)?

Tags: c++, database, database-template

is there anyone have read the source code of dtl in c++?
I found there is a class called variant_row, it used to store all kinds of data, and i tried to read the source code, but it is really hard for me, can someone explain how it is implemented and the class struct?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider investigating the implementation of BOOST.Variant and BOOST.Optional, They are definitions of a general purpose "generic" types.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/variant.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html